# Cannot enable desktop effects on a Thinkpad X220

Tags: 10.10, intel-graphics, thinkpad

My environment is as follows:
Laptop: Thinkpad X220, Intel HD graphics family(i915).
Dual-OS: Windows 7 professional, Ubuntu 10.10.

My problem is I cannot enable the desktop effects.
I have installed the xserver-xorg-video-intel using this commands:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:glasen/intel-driver
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-video-intel
```

and reboot.

However, when I attempted to enable the desktop effects, it displayed "searching available drivers", "desktop effects cannot enabled".
When I opened the "Additonal Drivers", there was no corresponding video driver available.

Who can tell me whether there is a trick when install or load the Intel i915 driver on Ubuntu 10.10 or not? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Also, try running:

```
glxinfo | grep direct
```

You shoul'd see an output telling you Direct rendering: yes
Otherwise, your graphic card is not being properly detected.